# Python - generate attributes of an object from a list

Tags: python, django, django-models, properties

I wish to generate an object from a list of properties in such a way:

```
class MyClass(MyBaseClass):
    __properties__ = ['property', 'nice_property', 'another_one']

    def __init__(self):
        MyBaseClass.__init__(self)

print(MyClass().property) #prints some default value
```

Probably I can add all of properties in a **init** of a base class. But then I have to execute it in each of subclasses. Can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is to set class attributes, like this:

```
class MyBaseClass(object):
    property = 'default'
    nice_prop = 'default'
    tralala = 'default'
```

All subclasses of MyBaseClass will have access to the properties. And the objects created from that class and subclasses. If you overwrite at object level any class property, it will be changed only for that object.

```
class SubClass(MyBaseClass):
     pass

sub_obj = SubClass()
print sub_obj.property # prints 'default'
sub_obj.property = 'new value'
print sub_obj.property  # prints new value
```

Comment: It is what I want to achieve, but I do not know the full list of properties before SubClass declaration.

Comment: Declare them in `SubClass` then.